# how to add pre-mint function (free mint open to everyone with limit of mint)

Tags: solidity, remix, function

I am trying to write a function that would allowed the first 2000 mint are free and then the contract stop until i start the public mint.

it would be be like two public mint, i guess.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your mint function you check if the current token id is less than 2000, if it is you dont charge any price, otherwise you charge the price. Example:

```
function mint(uint256 _amnt) public payable {
    uint256 alreadyMinted = totalSupply(); // see how many have already been minted
    if (alreadyMinted + _amnt >= 2000) {
        require(msg.value >= _amnt * cost);
    }
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _amnt;i++) {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, alreadyMinted + i); // mint the user there nft
    } 
}}
```

Im sure this can probably be cleaned up / optimised but this is a simple example.

Comment: And you can probably add a onlyOwner modifiable activeSell boolean for activating public mint after pre-mint, it will allow you to control starting of payable mints.

Comment: Thank you so much @nemo for your quick reply and help. I going to run some test.